# Displaying a preview of a word document using officeapps API and PHP output

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to display a preview of a embedded word document using Office's live view. I do not want to use a saved .docx file. I'm using a PHPWORD library to create the document using it's templateProccessing class.

Everything works when i'm referring to a path of a saved document but not as a php output.

What i have so far is

**HTML**

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://homeurl.com/panel/export?code=MYaM14lMfqm8NFYxpO67&id=43' ' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

And on the server side i have:

**PHP**

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $params['document_name']. ".docx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
$templateProcessor->saveAs("php://output");
```

The iframe preview says that it's unable to read the file.

I think it has something to do with the header information but i haven't found yet a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it doesn't work if file url doesn't contain filename and extension, just like in your case. Somehow it works if you modify your url:

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://homeurl.com/panel/export/file.docx?code=MYaM14lMfqm8NFYxpO67&id=43' ' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Can't find any documentation to find out if there is a better way to make it work.